# Fastest Way To Download Excel Data from server by VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro which downloads data from an online directory. The directory contains a file for each date:

- 29062016.csv
- 28062016.csv
- 27062016.csv

.. etc

My macro keeps my spreadsheet up to date with this data and downloads a file if it detects it is missing and copies it all to a single worksheet. So far so good.

I am using the following code within a loop to download each day that a user wishes to update (along with some control variables which keep count of rows).

```
Dim thisWb, downloadWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set downloadWb = Workbooks.Open("ftp://myusername:mypassword@address.com/directory/" & dateToDownload &".csv")
downloadWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:M" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=thisWb.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & CStr(rows))
downloadWb.Close
```

My issue is this method is slow as excel has to individually open each file then copy paste, especially when a few days haven't been updated.

I can ask my client to change their data feed so I was wondering if anyone could recommend a method to speed up data download, either by changing the feed or my code? Would it be faster to download and update from a single file containing all data (may become very large over time)? Different format .txt maybe? Would a http request be more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using SQL?

Comment: Likely the biggest factor here is the server bandwidth/latency: you should focus on that.  Opening a TXT file isn't likely to be significantly different from a CSV